# ggplot: update facet labels with number of points in the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

I have a dataset `data` and could plot according to the requirenmts as below:

```
#Data
data <- data.frame(level = c(1,2,3,5,2,4,3,1,3), 
                   pay1 = c(10,21,32,12,41,21,36,14,17), 
                   pay2 = c(26,36,5,6,52,12,18,17,19))

#Plot
data %>% pivot_longer(-level) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value))+
  geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_wrap(~ level, scales = "free_x") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

I wish to update the facet labels according to the frequency of another variable `level`.

```
table(data$level)
# 1 2 3 4 5 
# 2 2 3 1 1
```

How can the Facet labels be updated as `1 (n=2)`, `2 (n=2)`, `3 (n=3)`, `4 (n=1)`, `5 (n=1)`??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would just rename the factor levels with a `mutate` call that uses `paste` and `n()`:

```r
data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-level) %>%
  group_by(level, name) %>%
  mutate(level = paste0(level, " (n = ", n(), ")")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value))+
  geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_wrap(~ level, scales = "free_x") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: This answer works but is a workaround. If I run the code multiple times, the (n = x) gets added multiple times. Is there a better way?